# Apache Beam: Cannot find DataflowRunner

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run a pipeline, which I was able to run successfully with `DirectRunner`, on Google Cloud Dataflow. When I execute this Maven command:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
    -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.Pipeline \
    -Dexec.args="--project=project-name \
    --stagingLocation=gs://bucket-name/staging/ \
    ... custom arguments ...
    --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

I get the following error:

```
No Runner was specified and the DirectRunner was not found on the classpath.
[ERROR] Specify a runner by either:
[ERROR]     Explicitly specifying a runner by providing the 'runner' property
[ERROR]     Adding the DirectRunner to the classpath
[ERROR]     Calling 'PipelineOptions.setRunner(PipelineRunner)' directly
```

I intentionally removed `DirectRunner` from my `pom.xml` and added this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I went ahead and removed the `<scope>` tag, then called `options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class)`, but it didn't help. Extending my own `PipelineOptions` interface from `DataflowPipelineOptions` did not solve the problem as well.

Looks like it ignores `runner` option in a way I am not able to debug.

*Update*: Here is the full `pom.xml`, in case that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dataflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.4.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgetting to pass my PipelineOptions instance as a parameter to [`Pipeline.create()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/Pipeline.html#create-org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions-) method was the cause of my problem.

```
PipelineOptionsFactory.register(MyOptions.class);
MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options); // Don't forget the options argument.
...
pipeline.run();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had to add `
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>` to my dataflowrunner profile to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Which Dataflow SDK version are you using?

If you are using Dataflow 2.X you can use [DirectRunner](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/runners/direct/DirectRunner.html)

In Dataflow 1.X you can use [DirectPipelineRunner](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/apis)

You can also see the [Getting started instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-pipeline-java) which Suggest DataflowRunner and BlockingDataflowRunner (depending on your version). I suggest trying to get this working first if you can.

Comment: I can run the pipeline with no problems when I use `DirectRunner`, as I said in the question. Now I want to run it on Google Cloud Dataflow.


I am using 2.X version of SDK. I removed `DirectRunner` dependency from my `pom.xml` and put `DataflowRunner` [(as explained here)](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow) but couldn't get it to work.

I also tried running the pipeline from Google Cloud Dataflow's quickstart documentation and that worked perfectly.

Comment: I added all of the `pom.xml` to the question, in case it helps.

Comment: Are you sure that the --runner=DataflowRunner is part of the -Dexec.args="" option? If its outside of it then it will not work properly. I don't think that you should remove the direct runner dependency.

Comment: Yep, I am sure that it is inside `-Dexec.args=""`. When I don't remove the direct runner dependency, it just doesn't bother running it on Dataflow and falls back to direct runner.